# Website - Images won't load from server?

Tags: html, image, ftp, filezilla

I uploaded my website on my server with filezilla ([here](http://artotek.capoverde.fi)), but the images won't appear there. The images are in a folder called ''Kuvat'' on the server, but they cannot be retrieved from the server for some reason. I read a tutorial ([here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/images_no_show.htm)) but it was no use. It didn't help.

So the path is: Server -> Artotek -> Kuvat -> 3.gif
I've tried with ''/bla/bla'' and ''\bla\bla'' and ''..\bla\bla'' but neither one works.
(I'm aware of the infinite bugs on the site, it's just a testout version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your folder to kuvat, not Kuvat
Case sensitive makes the difference

Your website is currently looking for this image:
http://artotek.capoverde.fi/kuvat/3.gif Not found

Going to :
http://artotek.capoverde.fi/Kuvat/3.gif Image is here Voila!

Rename your Kuvat folder to kuvat and your website will know where to find your images

Comment: I just opened your website that shows no images, right clicked the image opening it in a new tab and changed the name of your folder in the url from kuvat to Kuvat and the image came up... you need to rename your image folder to kuvat, the same location your webpage img tags are looking for the images, kuvat is not the same as Kuvat

Comment: Oh.. It was just too simple for me; I guess. Works now, thanks.

Comment: Least you could do for the community was to upvote the correct answer as well?